# Bootstrap scrollspy does not work. It does not highlight "About"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to active/highlight "About" but when i scroll down for some space it become active/highlight. It should show highlighted "About" when i open it in browser. I want to active/highlight "About" when i do not move a scroll bar. "About" should be highlighted. Help me to solve this issue. "About" should be highlighted.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Han+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gugi" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira+Extra+Condensed:400,900" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    body {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    ul.nav-pills {
      top: 100px;
      position: fixed;
    }
    
    div.col-sm-9 div {
      height: 250px;
      font-size: 28px;
    }
    
    .bg-1 {
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    .bg-1 ul li {
      color: #ecf0f1;
      font-family: 'Gugi', cursive;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
    
    .bg-2 {
      width: 86%;
      background-color: #d1d8e0;
    }
    
    .col-sm-3 {
      width: 14% !important;
      background-color: white !important;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 810px) {
      #about,
      #education,
      #certifications,
      #skills,
      #projects,
      #experience,
      #interest {
        margin-left: 150px;
      }
    }
    
    #myScrollspy {
      position: fixed;
      align-self: center;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    #hello {
      font-family: 'Black Han Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 65px;
      margin-left: 150px;
      margin-top: 200px;
    }
    
    #name {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      font-size: 55px;
      font-weight: 600;
      margin-left: 150px;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
    
    #self {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: 500;
      margin-left: 150px;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
    
    #engineer {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: 500;
      margin-left: 150px;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
    
    #intro {
      font-family: 'Lora', serif;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #d1d8e0;
      margin-left: 150px;
      margin-top: 15px;
    }
    
    hr {
      width: 400px;
      border-top: 1px solid #4b6584;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #4b6584;
    }
    
    #education {
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    
    #email {
      font-size: 10px;
    }
    
    #headings {
      font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed', sans-serif;
      color: #343a40;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 50px;
    }
    
    #social {
      margin-top: -90px;
      margin-left: 250px;
    }
    
    .image {
      margin-left: 20px;
      padding: 1px;
    }
    
    .subheadings {
      font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed', sans-serif;
      color: #20bf6b;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 40px;
    }
    
    #certifications {
      margin-top: 350px;
    }
    
    .nav-pills>li.active>a,
    .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus,
    .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover {
      color: #fff;
      /* background-color: #337ab7; */
      background-color: unset !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="20">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row bg-1">
      <!--  Left Side Navigation Bar -->
      <div class="col-sm-3 text-center" id="backg">
        <nav id="myScrollspy">

          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked ">
            <img class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block image" src="naqqash.png" height="150" width="150 ">
            <li class="active"><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#education">EDUCATION</a></li>
            <li><a href="#certifications">CERTIFICATIONS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#skills">SKILLS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">PROJECTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#experience">EXPERIENCE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#interest">INTEREST</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

      </div>
      <!--  Right Side  -->
      <div class="col-sm-9 bg-2">
        <!-- About -->
        <div id="about">
          <h1 id="hello">hello</h1>
          <h3 id="name">I'm Muhammad Naqqash,</h3>
          <h3 id="self">a self taught developer.</h3>
          <h3 id="engineer">I'm a Computer Engineer. </h3>
          <p id="intro">I'm a positive and friendly person. Also, I love to set goals and achieve them.<br> My important qualities: self-motivated, ability overcome difficulties and the <br> ability to learn.</p>

          <div id="social">
            <a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-lg"></i><span style="display:inline-block; width: 5px;"></span>
            <a href=""><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-lg"></i></a> <span style="display:inline-block; width: 0px;"></span>
            <a href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-lg"></i></a><span style="display:inline-block; width: 5px;"></span>
            <a href=""><i class="fab fa-github-square fa-lg"></i></a><span style="display:inline-block; width: 5px;"></span>

          </div>


        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <!-- education -->
        <div id="education">
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <h1 id="headings">EDUCATION</h1>
          <h3 class="subheadings"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap fa-sm"></i><span style="display:inline-block; width: 20px;"></span>BS Computer Engineering</h3>
          <h3 class="subheadings"><i class="fas fa-university"></i><span style="display:inline-block; width: 20px;"></span>NUST College of E&ME</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="certifications">
          <h1 id="headings">Section 3</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="skills">
          <h1 id="headings">Section 4</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="projects">
          <h1 id="headings">Section 5</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="experience">
          <h1 id="headings">Section 6</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="interest">
          <h1 id="headings">Section 7</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Section 7</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Please try code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Han+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gugi" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira+Extra+Condensed:400,900" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    body {
      position: relative;
    }

    ul.nav-pills {
      top: 100px;
      position: fixed;
    }

    div.col-sm-9 div {
      height: 250px;
      font-size: 28px;
    }

    .bg-1 {
      background-color: black;
    }

    .bg-1 ul li {
      color: #ecf0f1;
      font-family: 'Gugi', cursive;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    .bg-2 {
      width: 86%;
      background-color: #d1d8e0;
    }

    .col-sm-3 {
      width: 14% !important;
      background-color: white !important;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 810px) {
      #about,
      #education,
      #certifications,
      #skills,
      #projects,
      #experience,
      #interest {
        margin-left: 150px;
      }
    }

    #myScrollspy {
      position: fixed;
      align-self: center;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
    }

    #hello {
      font-family: 'Black Han Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 65px;
      margin-left: 150px;
      margin-top: 200px;
    }

    #name {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      font-size: 55px;
      font-weight: 600;
      margin-left: 150px;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }

    #self {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: 500;
      margin-left: 150px;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }

    #engineer {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: 500;
      margin-left: 150px;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }

    #intro {
      font-family: 'Lora', serif;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #d1d8e0;
      margin-left: 150px;
      margin-top: 15px;
    }

    hr {
      width: 400px;
      border-top: 1px solid #4b6584;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #4b6584;
    }

    #education {
      margin-top: 0px;
    }

    #email {
      font-size: 10px;
    }

    #headings {
      font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed', sans-serif;
      color: #343a40;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 50px;
    }

    #social {
      margin-top: -90px;
      margin-left: 250px;
    }

    .image {
      margin-left: 20px;
      padding: 1px;
    }

    .subheadings {
      font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed', sans-serif;
      color: #20bf6b;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 40px;
    }

    #certifications {
      margin-top: 350px;
    }

    .nav-pills>li.active>a,
    .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus,
    .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover {
      color: #fff;
      /* background-color: #337ab7; */
      background-color: unset !important;
    }


  </style>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="20">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row bg-1">
      <!--  Left Side Navigation Bar -->
      <div class="col-sm-3 text-center" id="backg">
        <nav id="myScrollspy">

          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked ">
            <img class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block image" src="naqqash.png" height="150" width="150 ">
            <li class="active"><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#education">EDUCATION</a></li>
            <li><a href="#certifications">CERTIFICATIONS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#skills">SKILLS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">PROJECTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#experience">EXPERIENCE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#interest">INTEREST</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

      </div>
      <!--  Right Side  -->
      <div class="col-sm-9 bg-2">
        <!-- About -->
        <div id="about" class="section_div">
          <h1 id="hello">hello</h1>
          <h3 id="name">I'm Muhammad Naqqash,</h3>
          <h3 id="self">a self taught developer.</h3>
          <h3 id="engineer">I'm a Computer Engineer. </h3>
          <p id="intro">I'm a positive and friendly person. Also, I love to set goals and achieve them.<br> My important qualities: self-motivated, ability overcome difficulties and the <br> ability to learn.</p>

          <div id="social">
            <a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-lg"></i><span style="display:inline-block; width: 5px;"></span>
            <a href=""><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-lg"></i></a> <span style="display:inline-block; width: 0px;"></span>
            <a href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-lg"></i></a><span style="display:inline-block; width: 5px;"></span>
            <a href=""><i class="fab fa-github-square fa-lg"></i></a><span style="display:inline-block; width: 5px;"></span>

          </div>


        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <!-- education -->
        <div id="education" class="section_div">
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <h1 id="headings">EDUCATION</h1>
          <h3 class="subheadings"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap fa-sm"></i><span style="display:inline-block; width: 20px;"></span>BS Computer Engineering</h3>
          <h3 class="subheadings"><i class="fas fa-university"></i><span style="display:inline-block; width: 20px;"></span>NUST College of E&ME</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="certifications" class="section_div">
          <h1 id="headings">Section 3</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="skills" class="section_div">
          <h1 id="headings">Section 4</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="projects" class="section_div">
          <h1 id="headings">Section 5</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="experience" class="section_div">
          <h1 id="headings">Section 6</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="interest" class="section_div">
          <h1 id="headings">Section 7</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Section 7</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$( "#myScrollspy li" ).last().removeClass("active");
    //$( "#myScrollspy li" ).first().addClass("active");
    var navChildren = $("#myScrollspy li").children();
    var aArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < navChildren.length; i++) {
        var aChild = navChildren[i];
        var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
        aArray.push(ahref);
    }
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var docHeight = $(document).height();
        for (var i = 0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
            var theID = aArray[i];
            var secPosition = $(theID).offset().top;
            secPosition = secPosition - 135;
            var divHeight = $(theID).height();
            divHeight = divHeight + 90;
            if (windowPos >= secPosition && windowPos < (secPosition + divHeight)) {
                $("a[href='" + theID + "']").parent().addClass("active");
            } else {
                $("a[href='" + theID + "']").parent().removeClass("active");
            }
        }
    });

});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

## Below Script use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$( "#myScrollspy li" ).last().removeClass("active");
    //$( "#myScrollspy li" ).first().addClass("active");
    var navChildren = $("#myScrollspy li").children();
    var aArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < navChildren.length; i++) {
        var aChild = navChildren[i];
        var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
        aArray.push(ahref);
    }
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var docHeight = $(document).height();
        for (var i = 0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
            var theID = aArray[i];
            var secPosition = $(theID).offset().top;
            secPosition = secPosition - 135;
            var divHeight = $(theID).height();
            divHeight = divHeight + 90;
            if (windowPos >= secPosition && windowPos < (secPosition + divHeight)) {
                $("a[href='" + theID + "']").parent().addClass("active");
            } else {
                $("a[href='" + theID + "']").parent().removeClass("active");
            }
        }
    });

});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Hello @Muhammad Naqqash Please above code check and let me know.